# jquery set focus to dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery, setfocus, dynamic-content

I've run into this a number of times, where I wish to reset focus to (and or select the contents of) a dynamically generated element after failing some or other validation (typically on change or blur),  but I have never come up with a satisfactory solution. Why won't this work? [MyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UULW/)

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("body").append("<input type='text' id='test' size='5'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button>Go</button>");
    jQuery('body').on('blur', '#test', function()
    {   var test = jQuery(this).val();
        if(test && !isNumber(test))
        {   alert('Not a Number!');
            jQuery(this).focus().select();
            //jQuery('#test').focus().select();
        }
    });
});
function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `setTimeout` function:

```
$('#test').on('blur', function () {
    var $this = $(this), test = this.value;
    if (test && !isNumber(test)) { 
         setTimeout(function() {
            $this.focus().select();
         }, 4);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tFAaf/

Comment: Well slap me up and call me Ruth! I like it!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").append("<input type='text' id='test' size='5'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button>Go</button>");

    $('#test').on('blur', function() {   
        if (isNaN(this.value)) {   
            alert('Not a Number!');
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

If the element has no value when the user toggles out of the element, it focuses it and raises an alert. This is what you want, no?

Comment: Not sure what you've changed beyond removing.select(), but no, it doesn't work. That's where I started. Edit, my bad... you've alterend the event handler... let me test in fiddle and get back.

Comment: This event handler won't work as the element is dynamically appended. The OPs orignal `on()` signature was correct.

Comment: Well... color me surprised, as the event handler actually works in the fiddle (I didn't think it would either), however the focus still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
jQuery('body').on('blur', '#test', function()
```

should be:

```
jQuery(document).on('blur', '#test', function()
```

Comment: No, attaching the event to the `body` is perfectly fine. Attaching a delegated event handler to the `document` is the last thing you should do - it's the reason why `live()` was deprecated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   I understand the depreciated reasoning of `live()` . The user asked why it would not work in js fiddle. She had no body tag in html, or am i missing something.

Comment: there's always a body tag. jsFiddle adds it for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  okay got it, do not use fiddle that much. thanks.

Comment: No problems :) blah blah, content length warning etc.